# FontAwesome: How to transition from fa-spin to no spin

Tags: css, css-transitions, font-awesome

I need to remove the `fa-spin` class from an element once a process is completed.

The problem is there is no transition between the spinning icon and the non-spinning one.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  stopSpinner();
}, 2500);

function stopSpinner() {
  $('i').removeClass('fa-spin');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
```

Is there a way to add a nice transition so that it doesn't "jump straight" to the non-spinning icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pause the animation with [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state).

```
// css
.pause-spinner {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

// js (jQuery)
$("i").addClass("pause-spinner");
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably long past use for you, but you can use the `animationiteration` event to know when an iteration of the animation has finished, a la:

```js
var done = false;

setTimeout(function() {
  done = true;
}, 2546);

$('.fa-spin').on('animationiteration', function(event) {
  if (done) {
    $(event.target).removeClass('fa-spin');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `.fa-spin`, why not use CSS `transition`?

```js
$('i').addClass('spin');
```

```css
i {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.spin {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-refresh"></i>
```

Comment: Right. I've modified my Fiddle and it works sometimes. I don't know why is not consistent.
http://jsfiddle.net/emzero/9kqo1ter/1/

Comment: @emzero - I would suggest not using `.fa-spin`, since the time when its rotated `360deg` is unknown and adding `transition` with `.fa-spin` would rotate back to `0deg` after the `.fa-spin` class is removed.

Comment: But your snippet doesn't keep rotating... it just make a 360 rotation and that's it. I'm wanting to have it rotating during the process (hence the use of fa-spin which uses the animation css3 property) and once it's finished stop the rotation smoothly.
Check my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emzero/9kqo1ter/3/